# 1960’s sci-fi film black and white: lab in the woods with alien/monstrous woman being experimented on

Tags: story-identification, movie

Here is what I recall of the film:

- It took place somewhere in the woods and there was a laboratory in the woods. I think the main antagonist was a woman but almost alien or a monster of sorts. Like there was some experiment being done on her or by herself.
- There was a fight in a rowboat on a lake when a guy attacked a man and woman in the boat and they killed him with an oar and then they saw his back was horribly scarred maybe by radiation or something.
- The film is black and white for sure and I saw it on TV in the late 60’s and no later than early 70’s.

Here is what it is not although I thought it might be, any *She-Devil* or any of the main *She-* films. I have seen those recently and they are not it.

Comment: What about the ball?

Comment: @Valorum i guesss Sinolop meant "black"and white :p

Comment: Did you have a color TV already at that time?

Comment: Yes we did by then. The actors while not old I did not recognized as being new.

Answer (score 9):

["Terror from the Year 5000"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052286/) (1958).

I think this is the one. The plot involves a monstrous looking woman being brought from the future into our time by a scientist who is working in a laboratory in a wooded area. The full movie is available on YouTube and is posted below. You can see the scene where the man who attacked a man in a boat is revealed to have radiation burns on his back at 42:30 and the un-masking of the future woman revealing her to be a monster at 1:07:40 of the video.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cannot believe that anyone could find this. It is not listed on any 50's or 60's SCIFI film list. I saw it once on TV after school. I know this is a cheesy film but that scene I remember clearly.

Comment: Thank you Sinolop. You're right, it's very obscure with no name actors and very hard to find. At least the movie can now be seen on YouTube. Would you please select this as the best answer? Thank you.